# Centering an extensible div block

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to figure out why this code is not working. I want the buttons to be centered on the bottom of the page. I have the code to make them stay on the bottom of the page, but I just can't get them to center. Unless I use  but that doesn't "feel" like the way to do this.

See example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c99Hh/2/

HTML:

```
    <div id ="footer" style="margin:auto">
        <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But01</div>
        <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But02</div>
        <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But03</div>
        <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But04</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
            #footer{        
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 100%;
            }


            .nails-footer-buttons {
                -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
                -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
                box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #9dce2c), color-stop(1, #8cb82b) );
                background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #9dce2c 5%, #8cb82b 100% );
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9dce2c', endColorstr='#8cb82b');
                background-color:#9dce2c;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
                border-top-left-radius:15px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
                border-top-right-radius:15px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
                border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
                border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                text-indent:0;
                border:1px solid #83c41a;
                display:inline-block;
                color:#ffffff;
                    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                font-size:15px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-style:normal;
                height:60px;
                line-height:60px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-align:center;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #689324;
                    width: 70px;
            }
```

Tips much appreciated.

Comment: You can not center div by adding margin: auto when it has position fixed. Instead add left: 50% and margin-left: -50% width of div;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the style text-align:center to the footer element or to the CSS.

```
<div id ="footer" style="margin:auto;text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Added `margin:0 25%;`

CSS:

```
#footer{        
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 25%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="footer" >
    <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But01</div>
    <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But02</div>
    <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But03</div>
    <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But04</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c99Hh/3/

Comment: Can you explain to me why this works? It does work btw, but I want to know the impact.

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't fully center it, I will have to recalculate the % based on page width if I see it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c99Hh/7/)**

CSS :

```
  #footer{        
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left:50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            width: auto;
    }
```

You also need to remove `style="margin:auto;"` from your html markup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use align='center'

```
    <div id ="footer" align='center' >
       <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But01</div>
       <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But02</div>
       <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But03</div>
       <div class="nails-footer-buttons">But04</div>
    </div>
```

its not the best method but it should work

Comment: Works! But why is it not the best method? Will I run into issues later on?

Comment: you shouldn't have any issues, it's just that it isn't supported in html5 so if you are trying to get your website running with the latest code then it might not be the best method :)